# What is the algorithm Facebook comments use for "social" ordering

Tags: facebook, comments

There are [three types of orderings that a site that implements Facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#faqorder) can use:

> What are the different types of ordering for comments?
>
> **social aka "Social Relevance"**: The Comments plugin uses social signals
>   to surface the highest quality comments. Comments are ordered to
>   display the most relevant comments from friends and friends of friends
>   as well as the most-liked or active discussion threads. Comments
>   marked as spam are hidden from view.
>
> **time**: Comments are shown in the order in which they were posted, with
>   the oldest comments at the top, and the newest at the bottom.
>
> **reverse_time**: Comments are shown in the opposite order from which they
>   were posted, with the newest comments at the top, and the oldest at
>   the bottom.

What is the specific algorithm that determines the "social" ordering?  I'm especially interested in the details, like how "likes" may move it up the page (not hidden in the "view more" link), and does the ordering change for replies based on "likes" or edits?